# What does the notation $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ mean?

Tags: functions, notation

Alright, I've done research regarding this question have attained answers that identify $f$ as the function (which is obvious) and identify $\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ as meaning "the domain is the set of all real numbers and the codomain is the set of all real numbers",

I've also read that, say $f :  x \rightarrow x^2$ can be used as the notation for a function, and can otherwise be written as $f(x) = x^2$, which makes sense, but say for example, $f : 2\sqrt x \rightarrow \displaystyle \frac{x}{4}$, would this be equivalent to $f(x) = \displaystyle \frac{x^2}{64}$?

Furthermore, can the use of symbols indicating the sets of, for example, all real or rational numbers always be used to distinguish between when this notation is referring to a function and when it is referring to the domain and codomain of a function? All I would like is confirmation to these ideas so that I am aware of how to use them in the future. Thank you.

Comment: a function $f:A\to B$ is a special subset of the set $A\times B$. In general the usual notation to describe a function is like $f:A\to B,\, x\mapsto f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is explicitly described, by example as $x^2$, $\lfloor x\rfloor$, $\ln x$, etc...

Comment: I will enfatize the answer of Mathematician42: you **cannot** define a function properly if you dont says what is it domain and what is it codomain, so $f(x)=x^2$ doesnt define correctly a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $f:A\to B$ is read "f is a function from $A$ to $B$."  I always have imagined the colon to be "is a" or "has the type."  (You could potentially also write $f\in B^A$ if you are comfortable with $B^A$ being the set of functions $A\to B$.)

I wouldn't use $f:x\to x^2$ as notation for an algebraic definition of a function since, if $x$ is a set, it could mean "$f$ is a function from $x$ to the set of pairs of values from $x$."  Perhaps $f:x\mapsto x^2$, though I usually say "let $f$ be a function defined by $x\mapsto x^2$" or better "let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by $x\mapsto x^2$."  It is not unheard of to write $f=(x\mapsto x^2)$.

You may define a function implicitly, like $2\sqrt{x}\mapsto x/4$, but you *must* make sure it is well defined.  For instance, it cannot be defined for negative numbers since $2\sqrt{x}$ is not negative.  It is indeed equivalent to $f(x)=x^2/64$ if you make the domain of $f$ clear.

If I'm parsing it correctly, I think the answer to your last question is that you should use $\mapsto$ when you give an algebraic definition of a function and $\to$ when you give the type (domain and codomain) of a function.

Comment: Thanks for the response, is there a way in which I can identify the domain and range _and_ the function in one notation, or would it have to be written as $x \mapsto \displaystyle \frac{x^2}{64}$ and $Dom(f)=\mathbb R^+$ or $f : \mathbb R^+ \rightarrow \mathbb R^+$?

Comment: (Just in case: don't get the impression that learning math is about learning and using ever more cryptic notations.  Clear communication is key.)  If there is one, I have never used it. I'm pretty sure I only ever say something like "Let $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $x\mapsto x^2/64$." or "Let $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=x^2/64$.  If you insist, I could imagine $f(x:\mathbb{R}^+)=x^2:\mathbb{R}$, but don't do this unless you explain your notation to the reader.  (Be careful with the word range: it could mean "codomain" or "image.")

Comment: Why did you write the implicit function $2\sqrt x\mapsto \frac x4$ is equivalent to $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{64}\,?\,$ I think it should be $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{16}$.

Comment: @Angelo Now that it's been six years it's hard to say why I wrote this, but I'm guessing I trusted the original question. You're right: $(2\sqrt{x})^2/16 = 4x/16 = x/4$.

Answer (score 3):

You are making this more complicated than it is.

The proper notation for a function is $$f:X\rightarrow Y:x\mapsto f(x).$$
The part $f:X\rightarrow Y$ means that $X$ is the domain of the function and $Y$ is the target/codomain. The part $x\mapsto f(x)$ explains what happens to elements of $x$. Here a particular $x$ is mapped to $f(x)\in Y$.

In case the domain and target are understood, people often use the bad notation $f(x)=\mbox{some expression}$. For example $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, however this does not completely define the function as it is not clear what the domain and target are. Indeed comparing the functions $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]:x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+:x\mapsto f(x)$, we see that $f$ has a maximum whereas $g$ does not, a huge difference.

The notation $x\mapsto f(x)$ is the same story as it really only specifies $f(x)$.

Writing $f:2\sqrt{x}\mapsto \frac{x}{4}$ is not done. The problem is that you do not specify the domain and a priori it's not clear that any element in $X$ can be written as $2\sqrt{x}$. Indeed, writing $\sqrt{x}$ implies that $x$ should be positive, but when you rewritre this function as $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{64}$, this restriction dissapears.

For sake of completeness, let me give some examples of functions which have weirder domains and codomains.

Consider the map $f:C([0,1])\rightarrow \mathbb{R}:h\mapsto \max_{x\in [0,1]}h(x)$, it's non-trivial that this map is well-defined, i.e. the maximum exists. Here $C([0,1])$ is the set of all real-valued continuous functions on $[0,1]$. Here's another one $g:\mathbb{R}[X]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}[X]:p(X)\mapsto p'(X)$. Here $\mathbb{R}[X]$ is the set of all polynomials in $X$ with real coefficients and $p'(X)$ denotes the derivative of $p(X)$.

Comment: So, i.e. if I were to correctly write out the function in the question, would it be $f : \mathbb R^+ \rightarrow \mathbb R^+ : 2\sqrt{x} \mapsto \displaystyle \frac{x}{4}$, which means the domain and codomain of $f(x)$ has now been identified.

Comment: I have never seen the notation $f:X\to Y:x\mapsto f(x)$ before (in particular, the second colon).  Where have you seen this?

Comment: @joshuaheckroodt: You could write that, but it's bad practice. In order for that to make sense you need to explain that any element in $\mathbb{R}^+$ has a unique representation as $2\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: Thank you @Mathematician42

Comment: @KyleMiller: Are you serious? (Non-offensive, I'm just surprised). I know certain countries shuffle the order around, but other than that, this is standard notation. How do you write it?

Comment: @Mathematician42 I'm completely serious and also surprised.  I believe you if you say it is how you learned it, and it seems like reasonable notation (even if it doesn't seem "proper" or "standard" to me).  I learned to use "is defined by" for the second colon.

Comment: @KyleMiller: Two of the examples on the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics) under the notation tab use this style. I'm still very surprised, I encountered this expression in countless books and articles. It always made sense to me, all the ingredients for a function are there, in order even. Maybe I should look up the Bourbaki way of doing it.

Comment: @Mathematician42 I suspect you will find that most of the functions are "arbitrary." :-)   In all of the textbooks I've paged through just now, the closest I found was Neukirch's "Algebraic Number Theory," which has things like "the mapping $K\to K\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{C}$, $a\mapsto a\otimes 1$."  Turaev uses notation like $x\mapsto x^2:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}$ (and I think I've seen $f=(x\mapsto x^2):\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}$ before).  I cannot find the examples on that wikipedia page other than the notation $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}=x\mapsto x^2$.

Comment: @KyleMiller: This might be region and subject bound. Turaev's notation is the same although he reverses the order. I dislike the use of the equality sign in function as it doesn't make sense to me. I've read many books that use this notation (and others obviously). See for example, "tensor categories" by Etingof et al, "Quantum groups" by Kassel, books by Rotman and so on. Anyway, the key ingredients should be in the notation as simple as possible.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Would you believe Rotman, Kassel, and Etingof were among the books I looked through and didn't notice it?  Could you give me a page number?  (If you want to know how I make sense of the equals sign, I'm parsing it as $f=((x\mapsto x^2):\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R})$. The colon gives a judgment on the type of an anonymous function, which is assigned the name $f$.)

Comment: @KyleMiller: Page 15 in tensor categories shows a bifunctor (technically not necessarily a function, but still). I don't have the other books with me at the time but I'm sure I can find many examples. 

Also, I know how to parse the equality sign, I just don't like the notation.  The only point I wanted to make was that the OP's notation is not good enough. The alternatives suggested by you and I are clear enough.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Sorry, I misunderstood "it doesn't make sense to me" and missed the hyperbole or what "it" refers to.  Thanks for pointing out an example.